# Matplotlib version 1.5.3 vs 2.2.2 imshow on polar axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot using [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) in a polar graph. This worked in matplotlib version 1.5.3 but no longer works in version 2.2.2. Is there an alternate way to use do this? I know I can use [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) or [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) to do a similar thing, but I would highly prefer to use imshow. An example is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    print matplotlib.__version__
    data = np.random.randint(1, 100, (100, 100))

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
    ax.imshow(data, extent=[0, 2*np.pi, 0, 90])
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Version 1.5.3 Result:
[image: Version 1.5.3 Result:]
Version 2.2.2 Result:
[image: Version 2.2.2 Result:]

Comment: The problem with the 1.5 result is that is essentially wrong. It shows a cartesian imshow plot within a circle, but it's not a polar plot. So I guess it makes sense that this is not possible any more. Are you trying to get the same (wrong) result from 1.5 or are you trying to plot an image in a polar plot as the `extent` suggests? In the latter case the use of `pcolormesh` is indeed the solution - not clear why you would not like to use it.

Comment: I have data that is polar is nature but in Cartesian format, so I would like to plot with imshow, but to also show the polar coordinate system. So yes, i am trying to get the same wrong result, or I am looking for another way to overlay the polar axis and cutout the corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two axes, one cartesian axes in the background to show your image and a polar axes in the foreground to... be a polar axes as desired.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = plt.imread("https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/_images/sphx_glr_firefox_001.png")

fig = plt.figure()
#create axes in the background to show cartesian image
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax0.imshow(data)
ax0.axis("off")

# create polar axes in the foreground and remove its background
# to see through
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True, label="polar")
ax.set_facecolor("None")

plt.show()
```

[image]