# How to plot a background image in Mollweide view (Python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, astronomy

I am doing astronomical data analysis, using Sky Coordinates. How do I place an image as the background of a Mollweide view plot? What I've tried is to do the graph normally and add:

```
imag = mpimg.imread('gamma_ray_Fermi.png')
plt.imshow(imag)
```

But it just returns a deformed graph, instead of the usual plot with background.

Comment: Possibly this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826119/matplotlib-version-1-5-3-vs-2-2-2-imshow-on-polar-axis/50840267#50840267

Answer (score 2):

Found out how it works, thanks to the users ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment. This is the code that worked:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = plt.imread("yourimagehere.png")

fig = plt.figure()
#create axes in the background to show cartesian image
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax0.imshow(data)
ax0.axis("off")

# create polar axes in the foreground and remove its background
# to see through
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="mollweide", label="polar") 
#you can change to other projections like "hammer"
ax.set_facecolor("None")

plt.show()
```